# How do i get rid of this object required error?

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an "Object Required error" and it's highlighting my HSE variable

I've used this formula before to provide data verification for an input field to ensure a valid entry is given (against a database of about 40,000 PN's)
but for some reason the code is giving me a rough time this go around

```
Dim HSE As String
Dim Eff As Workbook
Eff = "---Filepath----"

Dim lay As Worksheet
Set lay = Eff.Sheets("Layline")

With lay.range("C:C")
Set HSE = .Find(txt_hose, LookIn:=xlValues)
If HSE Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Invalid Hose Material Value"
txt_hose.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
End With
```

Should take the value of the text box ("txt_hose") and conduct a search in the C column and all it checks is that there's an entry matching that value in the column and if not, it spits out an error message and ends the sub.
When I run it, it says "Object Required" and highlights HSE after the If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set` is for object-type variables only, and you've declared HSE as String.

You need:

```
Dim HSE As Range
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never had to dim it out before. I'm still pretty new at this :)